# is there a way to fit month wise date column into multivariate linear regression model with categorical data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

I tried Multivariate linear regression with categorical variables.
Used One hot encoder technique to solve the problem but got this error.

I have tried converting date string to timestamp using pd.to_datetime() function but then also it gave error like --
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

So I removed this thing and got backto solve the actual specified error using some alternative way..

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder() 
dfle = df    #df is the dataset containing column names ----- 'Section', 'BRAND', 'RSP', 'Monthstartdate', and 'Sales'*(to be predicted)* --------- 

dfle.Section = le.fit_transform(dfle.Section)  #Categorical values  (2 in number )
dfle.BRAND = le.fit_transform(dfle.BRAND)    #Categorical values (390 in number)

X = dfle[['Section', 'BRAND', 'RSP', 'Monthstartdate']].values

y = dfle.Sales



from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe =  OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])

X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Expected result was that the array could have been fit properly but getting this error.

Error -

---->  X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01/06/2016'

('01/06/2016' is string in this case, not timestamp, It would have been awesome if it could have been timestamp and working with the regression problem)

Comment: Sklearn does not officially support time data, though it might work occasionally. Maybe just transform timestamps to unix time

Comment: I usually use "months since first month" or "elapsed months" so the column would become 0,1,2,3,4,5... etc.

Comment: But then too, the year is an important factor I think. How can we ignore it? @JamesPhillips

Comment: Could you use both "month of the year" and "year"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Label encoder or vectorizer or tokenizer on all values of column before giving to one-hot encoder. 
The below code works fine on my side

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',delimiter=',')
df.head()
dfle = df.monthstartdate 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder() 
dfle = le.fit_transform(dfle)
feature = dfle
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe =  OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
feature = feature.reshape(feature.shape[0], 1)
feature = ohe.fit_transform(feature) 
print (feature)
```

I think you have missed 
dfle.monthstartdate = le.fit_transform(dfle.monthstartdate) in your code?

Comment: I think I have used Label Encoder on all values of specified columns(that contain categorical values). Can you please suggest what and where I am missing?